# Does a returning function has more performance overhead than the non-returning function?

Tags: c, performance, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I am at a situation where returning a value from a function is optional. So whether I return or don't return makes no difference logically, but can I safely assume the same thing performance-wise?

I mean are there any **performance overheads(time or memory)** when we use a function which returns some value(ex: `Int`) over the function which returns `void`?

This is a dummy project and the question is raised plain out of my curiosity.

Comment: There _might_ be a slight difference (I don't know for sure though) but it's probably negligible and bothering about that is probably not worth it - unless you're in a situation where you _really_ need that level of micro-optimization but in that case you'd have to dig deeper into byte code, hardware etc. anyway.

Comment: "whether I return or don't return makes no difference logically" ... You have a very weird design

Comment: Never ask such kind of questions. Results could be different on different systems. If you want to know: measure it (possibly with same environment of target system). If you cannot measure differences it means it doesn't matter.  See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: If you check the generated assembler (C)/byte(Java) code of each case it may tell you what you want to know.

Comment: We can't answer this question in a general manner, you need to have a specific system in mind. The answer depends on calling convention of the ABI, as well as whether or not the compiler can inline the function call. Though in general: extra functionality costs extra performance.

Comment: You don't have the choice in [tag:java]. so I have removed the tag.

Comment: If it "makes no difference logically" then don't return any value. What will the value be in the end if it is irrelevant? But if you return some information, don't ignore it at the calling site. What do describe sounds like a serious design error.

Comment: This is just a dummy project, the question is raised plain out of my curiosity. We can leave aside design worries.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the ABI used and whether the called function is inlined.

On x86_64 platforms with [System V Application Binary Interface AMD64](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) (Linux, FreeBSD, macOS, Solaris and Windows Subsystem for Linux) return values with `sizeof` of up to 16 bytes are returned in registers. Returning up to 16 bytes involves loading the return value into one or two 8-byte registers. Returning larger values involves stores into the stack of the caller through the hidden return value pointer passed into the callee, that also must be loaded in `rax` register upon return.

See [Calling conventions by Agner Fog](https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) for a detailed treatment of the calling conventions, in particular §7.1 Passing and returning objects. There are separate calling conventions for passing SIMD types in registers.